# How to create android application images?

Tags: android, image, performance, user-interface, android-image

I am planning to develop a new android application. I like to know what are the options available to create the resources (images).

As per my understanding, these are the only options i am aware of

1. Create nine-patch image using the draw nine-patch tool.
2. Use paint to create images of various size

Also, since android supports multiple density, i am planning to create resources specific to ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. Please suggest if this approach is good and what is the best way to create images of various densities (example - any tool to create those images or any website, etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Gimp too! For .png images. Or if you have a lot of money, you can buy Adobe Creative Suite etc...

Comment: @evilone, Thanks. I am looking for free tools only. I will check Gimp.

Comment: I recommend Inkscape. Makes it easy to create various resolutions of the same art, and it's free. You normally don't need to worry about ldpi, by the way. Since it is exactly half of hdpi, the OS can do a good job of scaling it from the hdpi resource. The exception is if the details of the icon become too jumbled at ldpi to be legible.

Comment: for simple shapes you can also look into xml drawables

Comment: have seen this ? http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 0):

This [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio) will give you a hand with Images, Icons, Colors and Styles.

It doesn't solve all the problems, like nine-patch creation, but it is definitely a useful tool. For that you can use the Nine-Patch tool: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html